# How to Dissolve Polygons Inside a Feature Class Based on Attribute Conditions

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, polygon, dissolve

I have a large shapefile (saleArea.shp) which includes hundreds of small adjacent polygons. I would like to dissolve the polygons based on some conditions from `tValues` field into 5 bigger groups like

```
1-  "tValues" <= 0.151560
2-  "tValues" >= 0.151561 AND "tValues" <= 0.254022
3-  "tValues" >= 0.254023 AND "tValues" <= 0.379095
4-  "tValues" >= 0.379096 AND "tValues" <= 0.540042
5-  "tValues" >= 0.540043 AND "tValues" <= 0.846651
```

I did this manually by using `Select By Attribute` for each of the groups then export them as a new shapefile. After that, I used the `Dissolve` tool on each of the layers and eventually merged all the dissolved layers - which  was tedious work (Besides I have more than 50 shapefiles and I must repeat this for all!). Can you please let me now how to do this is by Arcpy?

**Update**

I tried to do this as PolyGeo commented by using the Python parser

```
if ("tValues" <= 0.151560):
        return 1
elif ("tValues" >= 0.151561 AND "tValues" <= 0.254022):
        return 2
elif ("tValues" >= 0.254023 AND "tValues" <= 0.379095):
        return 3
elif ("tValues" >= 0.379096 AND "tValues" <= 0.540042):
        return 4
elif ("tValues" >= 0.540043 AND "tValues" <= 0.846651):
        return 5
```

but I am getting this error

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are using [consistent spacing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-field-examples.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_DF13F7EE4AF345CAAA46C1CFA2F7BFE1). Take a look at the examples for code blocks and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use ArcPy for this.

You can use the Field Calculator with its Python parser and if/elif(x4) to return values of 1 to 5 to a field, perhaps called GROUP.

You can then Dissolve on GROUP to get the five features that you desire.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, this sounds interesting but the first part looks a little bit confusing! Can you please let me know how to do this?

Comment: @Behseini Polygeo means that you should add a new field and compute the class values with the field calculator. See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113407/if-then-field-calculator/113753#113753 for an example of if statement. You can add all your condition if/elif/elif/elif/else

Comment: Thanks radouxju, well,  it seems juicy but not sure hoe to write the expression for example to return 2 for all `"tValues" >= 0.151561 AND "tValues" <= 0.254022`

Comment: Thanks PolyGeo, Can you please take a look at the update code and let me know what I am doing wrong on the code?

Comment: @Behseini In that code you are asking whether the string `"tValues"` is `>= 0.151561` - you need to test whether the current value of a number variable called `tValues` is `>= 0.151561` i.e. use `tValues >= 0.151561`.  Also, questions like this are usually easy to debug if you also include a screenshot of the tool dialog so that we can see you have set the Parser, Expression and Code Block all correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If anything becomes tedious and repetitive then it's time to get smarter with your processing. You can automate all that you described by using modelbuilder. You drag the tools you used in to modelbuilder, connect them together to create a work flow and then run the model. You'll invest a bit of time creating the model but then you can tweak a parameter and run the whole model again. There are even ways of making the model loop (called iterators).  Basically it's time for you to read the Help manual! Go to Desktop > Geoprocessing > Modelbuilder.

Comment: Actually I already did but not sure why it is not working properly! I mean I am getting 5 Classify at the end but not sure why the last classify over lap on top of all